# Parent-child relationship: multiple tables vs. self-join

Tags: sql, database, database-design, join, relationship

I'm working on a database for stat keeping for a sports club where I help administrate some events.  I think I've got the parts for keeping track of the competitor names, classifications, categories, etc. figured out using a main table, several lookup tables and a couple bridge tables to cover the many-to-many relationships involved.

I have a model sketched out for the next part, but I'm not entirely comfortable that I'm doing it right.  I know how we do it on paper and/or in a spreadsheet where I'm still doing a lot of manual work, but I'm not 100% confident I'm 'translating' it to tables and relations correctly.

A simple event structure might look like this:

```
Tournament  
- Day 1  
    - Match 1 (Fired Match)  
    - Match 2 (Fired Match)  
    - Match 3 (Fired Match)  
  - Match 4 (Aggregate Match of 1,2,3)  

- Day 2  
    - Match 5 (Fired Match)  
    - Match 6 (Fired Match)  
    - Match 7 (Fired Match)  
  - Match 8 (Aggregate Match of 5,6,7)  

 - Match 9 (Aggregate Match of 4,8)
```

I had broken things down a bit further and have tables for 'scores', 'stages', 'matches', and 'tournaments' (among others).  The idea being that scores are the raw data I need to record for each competitor, with foreign keys to the 'competitor' and 'stages' table.  Rather than having 'fired' and 'aggregate' matches, I decided to approach it as matches being aggregates of one or more stages, and tournaments can have one or more matches (aggregates).

[image: ERD]

I left out some of the lookup tables indicated by the other foreign keys since they don't directly relate to the matter at hand which I guess is "Is this the correct way to go about this, or would I be better off to skip the matches/stages separation?  Would there be a way to reimplement this parent-child relationship between matches and stages in a single table via a self-join?

Comment: If a match is an aggregate of one or more stage, wouldn't that be better served to be either a view or a materialized view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a properly normalized and flexible hierarchical structure to me.

As designed, it implies that a Tournament has one or more Matches, and a Match has one or more Stages... or, more to the point, each parent has a variable number of children, where the number is always greater than zero but can and will vary from instance to instance. If this is not the case, if a parent (Tournament or Match) will always have the same number of children, then there might be some minor advantage in denormalizing the data (like a table with seven columns for the weekdays) , but that may prove awkward in the long run.

I would definitely not do a single table with a self join, as the different levels of the hierarchy contain different attributes. For example, "Shots" is part of a Stage and not part of a Match, and so should not be made part of the Match table.

Comment: 'Typically' a tournament has one grand agg i.e. one overall 'match winner' but for technical reasons that may be changing - either we have to have separate 'tournaments' on paper for different groups competing side by side (but not head to head), or have one tournament able to have multiple grand agg matches, one for each group.

Shots could be part of a stage or a match, although it'd probably be easier to calculate the shots in a match from the aggregate of the child stages...